# Generating keys that refer to to the seed when put together in any combination

Tags: logic, pseudocode

I'm attending a course in programming where I as given the following assignment. I couldn't think of a valid algorithm hence my question.

A bank has a code for it's vault which is 489652. According to the rules of the bank, to open the vault, 3 of the 10 managers have to agree on opening. Any 3 of them should be able to open the vault, but only 2 of them won't suffice.

Construct an algorithm that generates 10 keys, one for each manager.

Comment: Surprised this is a programming course versus cryptography course.  I think you want: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir's_Secret_Sharing

Comment: Seems to be it, thank you!